# How to add output variable from props React JS

Tags: html, react-props

So I tried to make a kind of web to add up the fees from each division.

I'm trying to sum from the output props. However, the sum is not correct. The output
instead adding each number from the user input until it becomes like the following image:

[image: my image]

And the correct sum should be 58625 right?

Here's the code:

```
{props.users.length > 0 ? (
    props.users.map(user => (
      <tr key={user.id}>
        <td>{user.name}</td>
        <td>{user.cabang * 25}</td>
        <td>{user.dealer * 40}</td>
        <td>{user.cod * 60}</td>
        <td>{user.jtr * 65}</td>
        <td>{user.gosend * 75}</td>
        <td>{user.reguler * 200}</td>
        <td>{user.total = user.cabang + user.dealer + user.cod + user.jtr + user.gosend + user.reguler}</td>
        <td>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              props.editRow(user)
            }}
            className="button muted-button"
          >
            Edit
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => props.deleteUser(user.id)}
            className="button muted-button"
          >
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ))
  ) : (
    <tr>
      <td colSpan={3}>No users</td>
    </tr>
  )}
```

How to add up correctly?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The values are been considered as a string, you need to convert them into integer before you add.

You can user either parseInt() or number() do it as below given code

```
<td>{user.total = parseInt(user.cabang) + parseInt(user.dealer) + parseInt(user.cod) + parseInt(user.jtr) + parseInt(user.gosend) + parseInt(user.reguler)}</td>
```

Complete Code

```
{props.users.length > 0 ? (
props.users.map(user => (
  <tr key={user.id}>
    <td>{user.name}</td>
    <td>{user.cabang * 25}</td>
    <td>{user.dealer * 40}</td>
    <td>{user.cod * 60}</td>
    <td>{user.jtr * 65}</td>
    <td>{user.gosend * 75}</td>
    <td>{user.reguler * 200}</td>
    <td>{user.total = parseInt(user.cabang) + parseInt(user.dealer) + parseInt(user.cod) + parseInt(user.jtr) + parseInt(user.gosend) + parseInt(user.reguler)}</td>
    <td>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          props.editRow(user)
        }}
        className="button muted-button"
      >
        Edit
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => props.deleteUser(user.id)}
        className="button muted-button"
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
))
) : (
    <tr>
      <td colSpan={3}>No users</td>
    </tr>
  )}
```

Comment: But why it's become string? I create the object with value number

Comment: Need to look at the complete code flow to understand why its been coming as a string. might be while assigning, the values are in quotes (" ").